# How can I deny access to a folder in OpenLiteSpeed similarly to the way Apache does it?

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, deny, litespeed

I'm trying to deny access to a folder for a website that is hosted with [OpenLiteSpeed v1.4.2](http://open.litespeedtech.com/mediawiki/index.php/Release_Log/1.x#V1.4.2), but I'm have trouble. I take it that `.htaccess` isn't supported in OpenLiteSpeed so I am unable to just put a `.htaccess` file with `Deny From All` in it in the folder.

Let's say the absolute path to the folder I’m trying to hide is `/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/hideme`. I’ve tried to put the following into the rewrite rules for the virtual host in the OpenLiteSpeed panel but have had no luck:

```
<Directory ~/hideme>
  Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory ~/hideme/(.*)$>
  Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/local/lsws/Example/html/hideme>
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong and how I can deny access to this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this [sample config file from a GitHub mirror](https://github.com/aheadley/OpenLiteSpeed/blob/master/dist/DEFAULT/conf/vhconf.conf) of the [open source repo for OpenLiteSpeed](http://open.litespeedtech.com/mediawiki/) it seems like the config would be something like this:

```
context {
  uri /hideme/
  accessControl {
    deny 
  }
  location hideme/
}
```